# Is there a way to find number of subscribers from a playlist URL?

Tags: spotify

I'm making a spotify app that I want to show the number of subscribers from a given playlist URL submitted by a user.

I have looked around their documentation but can't seem to find much useful information.

Thanks!

EDIT: I would like to use the web API as I don't really know C. Hopefully it's still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web API doesn't support any playlist lookup at all, so unfortunately this isn't possible.

libSpotify supports this (see [sp_playlist_num_subscribers](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group__playlist.html#ga967ad87f0db702513ecda82546f667c5)), but be aware you need to have the user log into their Spotify account before this can be done, which may not be what you're wanting to do.

Comment: would this be possible with the C library they provide? Input as URL, output as number of subscribers?